# Deleting large temp files created in Image Analysis

Tags: raster, arcmap

I have a question about large temp files generated using Image Analysis in ArcMap.

I have been working with large digital elevation modesl and have been using Image Analysis to create hillshade and slopeshade maps for many (>2 GB) datasets. The files are supposedly stored as a temp file under appData and are equivalent in size. My C drive is filing up fast and I can't access the temporary folders. Is there any way I can get rid of these files so that I can free up disk space?

The path is: *AppData\Local\Temp\1\arcD660: but there are no files visible

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to establish an ARCTMPDIR directory?

Comment: These files appear in your current workspace, which is usually the path listed (the last part is unique to the session). Are you showing hidden files? The %APPDATA% location is changeable, set your %TEMP% and %TMP% environment variables https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10#:~:text=Open%20Control%20Panel.,for%20your%20user's%20environment%20variables. to a folder on a disc that *does* have some space and scratch data will appear there, do so likewise with environment workspace and scratchWorkspace.

Comment: As for locating and removing the files that do exist, do a Ctrl + F find for hdr.adf on your system drive, these files will appear within a GRID which is what Esri uses for temp storage, go up one level and remove all the GRIDs at once, including the info folder (contains arc.dir) which is related to these temporary grids.